# What are the top 3 main concepts in WPF?

Tags: wpf

What are the top 3 main concepts in WPF that you need to understand in order to write good WPF code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the most important aspects of WPF concepts are:

- Templates and Styles (the way you define the behaviour and appearance of your application)
- Data Binding (the way you should glue together your UI with your business objects
- Declarative UI definition through XAML

Maybe there are other elements but in my opinion those are fundamental for WPF thinking.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the single most important concept is the UI pattern Model-View-ViewModel, or as I like to call [Model-View-ModelController](http://codingcontext.wordpress.com). This is crucial to building apps successfully in WPF. Besides that, the real conerstones are Databinding, Templating, and Styles as others have mentioned. There is a nice post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322612/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-made-in-wpf-development) on some common pitfalls to avoid when developing in wpf.

Answer (score 2):

The real basics that you have to grok is:

- XAML
- Layout
- Content model
- Data binding

Their are loads more but these are the ones that has changed the most from winforms...

Also check out this thread: [Interview questions: WPF Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739/interview-questions-wpf-developer)

Answer (score 1):

I duno about top 3 but Attached/Dependency properties is pretty important.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two big main concepts in WPF

In no particular order:

- Bindings
- Templating and Styles

When you have learned those two concepts, you will be able to write decent WPF code...

Oh, and the third would be XAML.. but that is the language... however, you might want to try to put as little in the code behind and as much in your XAML file...

Its quite easy to choose the code behind approach, but try to do it in XAML in stead...

Answer (score 1):

The most concept in WPF lies on the stype and the behavior of the UI. It has lot of features, among them the following three are the most useful and important aspect.

1. Building the data binding of the business object and UI.
2. Changing style and more user friendly as to easy implement in UI so that the look and fill is good as user perspective.
3. Redefining the UI through the XAML and changing the font, style, implementing animation etc.
   So its most powerful concept.

Answer (score 0):

To know more about the technology, one should know about the architecture of a technology. However following are the basic but most important concepts in WPF are -

1) XAML
2) Rich Layout, Panels and Windows
3) Content model
4) Data binding