# WPF/Silverlight Interview Questions?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

What kind of questions would you expect someone to know during an interview for a job doing WPF/Silverlight development?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739/interview-questions-wpf-developer

Comment: Here are 100 WPF interview question with detail answer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/744082/WPF-Interview-questions-with-answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Entry Level

- Strong .NET 2.0 Background & willing to learn!
- Explain dependency properties?
- What's a style?
- What's a template?
- Binding
- Differences between base classes: Visual, UIElement, FrameworkElement, Control
- Visual vs Logical tree?
- Property Change Notification (INotifyPropertyChange and ObservableCollection)
- ResourceDictionary - Added by a7an
- UserControls - Added by a7an
- difference between bubble and tunnel routing strategies - added by Carlo
- XAML

## Mid-level

- Routed Events & Commands
- Converters - Added by Artur Carvalho
- Explain WPF's 2-pass layout engine?
- How to implement a panel?
- Interoperability (WPF/WinForms)
- Blend/Cider - Added by a7an
- animations and storyboarding
- ClickOnce Deployment
- Skinning/Themeing
- Custom Controls
- How can worker threads update the UI?
- DataTemplate vs HierarchicalDataTemplate
- ItemsControl vs ItemsPresenter vs ContentControl vs ContentPresenter
- Different types of Triggers
- How to do Animations through StoryBoards

## Advanced

- Example of attached behavior?
- What is PRISM,CAL & CAG?
- How can worker threads update the UI?
- WPF 3D - Added by a7an
- Differences between Silverlight 2 and WPF
- MVVM/MVP - Added by a7an
- WPF Performance tuning
- Pixel Shaders
- Purpose of Freezables

Rest here : [Interview questions: WPF Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739/interview-questions-wpf-developer)

Comment: huh... guess I'm advanced... all I'm missing is WPF3D... Pixel shaders i haven't worked with, but I get.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head:

- What is a Template, and why are they used.
- How does WPF/SL manage resources in XAML
- What is the "x" xmlns
- What are markup extensions
- What is data binding, talk about it a little, tell me why it's awesome

Comment: If you're hiring btw, poke me ;-)

Comment: Yes an no. My current employeer is hiring, but there is very little WPF work there. I'm asking because I've got my own interview tomorrow at Cynergy Systems. My friend works there and he says the place is just awesome.

Comment: I got the job and have been there for two weeks. It turned out to be a great plaace and I would highly recommned it to anyone else looking to focus on UI work.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen is there a link to the career's page?

Answer (score 1):

How do asynchronous calls work in Silverlight and what considerations must you take into account (if any) when working with them?

Comment: asynch + await.... I mean... uh... ;-)

Comment: I am so looking forward to using those. Porting my WPF code to Silverlight has been a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

- What features are only available when
  using Silverlight Out of Browser?
- Explain how the Print functionality
  works in Silverlight 4? and any
  issues you can think regarding it?
- What are the different ways
  Silverlight can access Services?

  This site has some useful questions for basic Silverlight Knowledge - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/QuestionsOnSilverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean if a control is virtualized?

What tactics can be used to reduce the initial XAP download? subsequent downloads?

What is isolated storage? How much of it do apps get? Can they get more?