# What should I learn in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have C#, ASP.NET experience and have started learning Silverlight. What are the areas I should take a look at, to know at least the basics of Silverlight?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to start a project and then ask *specific* questions *if* you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at this SO thread: [WPF/Silverlight Interview Questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327612/wpf-silverlight-interview-questions)

Now these are interview questions but on the flip side they provide a good list of bullet points to start climbing the Silverlight development ladder.

Answer (score 1):

Choose and learn an MVVM framework that works with Silverlight.
I like both [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/) and [MVVM light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).