# WPF level intermediary

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm having an interview with a client tomorrow regarding a WPF project I might work on.

I'd like your expert advises regarding what is an **intermediary** level in WPF to ensure that I'm in a good standing, because I'm a little bit freaking out.

Could you please state what points an **intermediate** wpf developer should master ?

Thank you

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739/interview-questions-wpf-developer

Comment: @Meleak: thank you !
@RQDQ: Your comment is pointless though, but thank ya anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose: xaml (of course!), dependency properties, routed events, controls, commanding system, syles, drawing, templates, bindings, and a bit of animations.

Comment: Thanks ! I was seeking for such a listing actually :) Kr.